# Stop Bluetooth Keyboard from Sleeping

Tags: windows, keyboard, script, bluetooth

I got [this](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/surface-tastatur/8r3rqvvflp4k) new keyboard. After being 10 Minutes inactive, the keyboard cuts its Bluetooth connection to save battery. Now when I want to type then, the keyboard needs 3-5 Seconds re-connection time, which is quite annoying.

Now my Question: How can I prevent the keyboard from cutting the Bluetooth connection. I thought of some script that somehow activates the keyboard every 5 minutes or so, but maybe there are better options than this.

Disabling the "Save Energy" function in Device Manager Settings isn't working for me. BTW: I'm using an external Bluetooth Receiver.

Comment: Try go into device manager, right click on bluetooth and display property. select power management tab. uncheck the box “allow the computer to turn off this device to save power”.

Comment: already did that, doesn'T work

Comment: Try: (1) Assure the system service “Bluetooth Support Service” has Startup type of Automatic. (2) Assure “Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power” is unchecked for the keyboard/Bluetooth under: “Bluetooth Radios”, “Mice and other pointing devices” and “System devices”.

Comment: Did everthing you mentioned. Still disconnects.

Comment: Can you try to boot your windows in safe mode just to see if the behaviour is the same?

Comment: will do when at home

Comment: There is a comment on the Microsoft Community site: "(...) my Bluetooth keyboard did not come with a driver. Windows 10 was using a standard HID type Bluetooth driver. The power settings were actually in the HID properties and not the keyboard properties." Does that make a difference?

Comment: The branch "Human Interface Devices" in Device Manager is indeed another place to search for the device and verify its setting of “Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power”.

Comment: nothing worked. still facing this issue

Comment: Try this answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596610/bluetooth-mouse-sleeps-after-a-few-seconds-idle-when-there-is-no-other-mouse-con/679811#679811

Answer (score 4):

You should first assure that the system service “Bluetooth Support Service” has
the Startup type of Automatic.

Then you should go into the Device Manager, locate all concerned devices connected
to keyboard or Bluetooth and uncheck in their properties the property of
“Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power”.

There are several classes of devices where such devices may be found, and you
should search in all of them:

- Bluetooth Radios
- Mice and other pointing devices
- System devices
- Human Interface Devices

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-usb_power_save.rules` sorted out my issue with my Microsoft keyboard and mouse.

By adding this on one line:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0cf3", 
ATTR{idProduct}=="e500", ATTR{power/autosuspend}="-1"
```

I looked up the vender idVender and idProduct numbers with the `lsusb -tv` command.  `usbview` might a useful utility to install as well.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596610/bluetooth-mouse-sleeps-after-a-few-seconds-idle-when-there-is-no-other-mouse-con/679811#679811

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596610/bluetooth-mouse-sleeps-after-a-few-seconds-idle-when-there-is-no-other-mouse-con/679811#679811